# Dropdownlistfor in mvc razor with font awesome icons

Tags: font-awesome, dropdownlistfor

I have a strongly typed view with dropdownlistfor for rating

```
 public class EmployeeRating
 {
  public  int RatingId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RatingList> RatingList { get; set; } 
 } 

 public class RatingList
 {
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

In my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>EmployeeRatings.RatingId,new SelectList(ViewBag.RateList, "Value", "Text", EmployeeRatings.RatingId),
                                                    "Select Rating", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

I have ratings like GOOD,POOR,AVERAGE.
To this I need to add related font awesome icons and display in my view .But it is not rendering icons,instead showing **`<i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>` Good**.
Then I tried with UNICODE of FA icons.But not displaying icons(showing UNICODE in dropdownlist).
I tried like this

```
RatingList = new List<RatingList>();

RatingList.Add(new RatingList { Value = 1, Text = "&#xf118; Good" });
RatingList.Add(new RatingList { Value = 2, Text = "&#xf11a; Average" });
```

I could not even find any  helper tags which does this work.Also I need to **give color to each item** something like **smiley Good-Green  ,frown Poor-Red , meh Average -Orange**.

I am doing this from past two days and still no luck.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to render FA icons in dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSiteID, Model.Sites, null, new { @id =   "siteSelection", @onchange = "siteChanged(this)", @class = "siteSelector" })  
<i style="position:absolute;top:10px;font-size:24px;right:15px;color:white;pointer-events:none;" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```